# Object/namespace and self invoking functions

Tags: javascript

If i create a name space object

```
name.Name({ })
```

e.g

```
name.Name({ 
var:"value",
{name:prop},

func : function(){}

})
```

How do you execute a self invoking function, something like: `(function(){return var})()` within this object and available throughout this object?

Comment: im not sure i understand where is this function being executed?

Comment: If you invoked it, it will no longer be available as a function. You'll only have its return value. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
name.Name({
    "someProperty": (function() {
         return 42;
     })()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not fully understand the question, but if you have an instance of the object, you can use

```
instance.func
```

Or in a callback inside

```
this.func
```